# Очередь на 6ти стеках

Tags: c++, ооп, структуры-данных, сложность

хочу написать очередь (с нуля на с++) используя 6  стеков(так как прочитал что ее можно написать так, чтобы любая операция выполнялась за О(1)) 1) Я не могу понять как количество стеков влияет на скорость работы. И вообще как это сделать. Вариант с двумя стеками я писал.

Comment: Как же вы собрались писать если не понимаете как это работает? :)

Comment: Откуда идея использовать 6 стеков? Первый раз про такое слышу.

Comment: не может очередь работать за О(1) с любыми операциями, хоть ты лопни.... дайте ссылку на источник, где вы об этом узнали

Comment: https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C

Comment: Все  же не понимаю, чем список не угодил? все операции O(1), единственный минус - определенный перерасход памяти; у вас такое количество элементов в очереди, что это становится важным? А что не можете понять - ну там же ссылка на описание: https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C

Comment: Но, кстати, нигде не рассматривается вопрос размера стеков - т.е. при большой очереди может случиться так, что нужно будет либо перераспределение памяти стеков (амортизированная O(1)), либо реализовывать стеки на списках - тоже же накладные расходы (хотя и могут быть меньшими), либо выделять под стеки большое место заранее - опять же память будет тратиться впустую. Словом, очередь на стеках, а стеки - на чем? :)

Comment: почему 6? я вот люблю цифру 7? Все за константу по контейнеру - вы наверное работаете в 1C?

Comment: тут речь о средней амортизированной стоимости операций